# Better error reporting with "heroku local"?

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to have more descriptive error reporting with when using the `heroku local` command? Currently it just shows the file name and line number but doesn't actually say what has gone wrong.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I'm wondering the same thing...

Comment: Same here. No information can be found online regarding this. I assume what we are looking for is a way to access local logs.

Comment: Have not gotten an answer to this